# Dynamic keyword insertion

Tags: php, html

I'm using this code to pass some information from my url to my webpage.

```
mysite.com/?v=keyword

<a href="mysite.com/?<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['v']); ?>"></a>
```

My problem is I need a default keyword when traffic goes to my site and the referring link is not passing information from the url.

I need a default keyword if no information is passed. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 4):

The default should be set in your PHP file.  You can use a ternary operator based on `isset()`.  If the condition is true, the first value (after `?`) will be used, if the condition is false, the second value (after `:`) will be used.

```
$keyword = (isset($_GET['v'])) ? $_GET['v'] : 'default';
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if (isset($_GET['v'])) {
   $keyword = $_GET['v'];
}
else {
   $keyword = 'default';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['v'])){
    $keyword = htmlspecialchars($_GET['v']);
}else{
   $keyword = "Something" ;
}
echo "<a href='http://somesite.com/?$keyword'>$keyword</a>";
?>
```

Learn more about [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

---

---

Alternatively you can use `!empty` (not empty)

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['v'])){
    $keyword = htmlspecialchars($_GET['v']);
}else{
   $keyword = "Something" ;
}
echo "<a href='http://somesite.com/?$keyword'>$keyword</a>";
?>
```

Learn more about [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)